# Drivers for Pressure Sensitivity on Microsoft Surface Pro (First Generation) running 14.10

Tags: drivers, surface

I was able to get Ubuntu dual booting alongside Windows 8.1 on my Microsoft Surface Pro without much trouble thanks to all the great tutorials I was able to easily find. Ubuntu works great out of the box for almost everything: touch, wi-fi, sound.
The show stopper for me is that **it doesn't seem to recognize the pressure sensitivity needed for creating digital art.** I actually installed the 14.04 LTS and then upgraded to 14.10 in hopes that it might have the issue resolved. But it did not.
Can someone help me out?

Please and thanks,

-Jim